# Integer length java hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, integer

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I have the following property in my hbm

and I think when field1 is being persisted in the database i'm getting the following error:

ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column

The value of field1 when i'm persisting is 2122450943, the database field length is Number(18) but is it because of the HBM which has it's length 6 that i'm getting this error? Also, I have tried to change the length to 12 from 6 to see if it works, don't have the data though. Can Integer have a length 12? Is that number 6 or 12 the number of digits or length of the number?

Comment: It might sound like bad practice but when I'm not sure of how long a number might be, I don't specify a length for the field. E.g. ID could be any length so I just leave it. (It's not that bad if it's small/personal projects)

Comment: Why do you think it is field1 and not another field?

Answer (score 0):

Which database are you using.

In MySQL int value cannot have the length more than 10.

Not sure about other RDBs.

Comment: So there must not be any problem on that, because in Oracle, the INTEGER datatype is usually referred to as NUMBER(38). Its precision can range from 1 to 38.

Comment: so does that mean that my hibernate property definition of Integer(6) doesn't mean anything?